# Таблицы стилей css по умолчанию в разных браузерах

Tags: css

Какие стили css присваиваются браузерами по умолчанию?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду HTML-страницу без использования CSS? Если да, то тогда каждый браузер имеет свой набор правил CSS, которые по умолчанию присваиваются различным тегам.

Comment: хороший же вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вопрос хороший, никто и не спорит, просто он не раскрыт полностью. Ну я смысл как понял, так и пояснил в комментариях.

Answer (score 6):

Вот здесь стандартные стили -webkit- [default webkit browsers](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)

Вот здесь стандартные стили -moz-  [default mozilla browsers](https://hell.meiert.org/core/css/firefox-3.0b3.css)

Вот здесь стандартные стили safari [apple webkit safari](https://hell.meiert.org/core/css/safari-x.css)